# Cannot clone GIT repository using SSH

Tags: git, gitlab

**In Windows**:

When cloning GIT repository, I can do this successfully:

```
git clone https://user@gitlab.example.com/clientes/sample/project.git
```

However, when I do:

```
git clone ssh://user@gitlab.example.com:17177/clientes/sample/project.git
```

After the log in banner is displayed, this error is shown:

```
fatal: '/clientes/sample/project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**In MacOS**:

When using HTTPS way, a SSL certificate expired error is shown.

When using SSH way, the same error as Window.

How can I solve those problems?

Comment: Seems like `/clientes/sample/project.git` is not a git repository on that server. `How can I solve those problems?` Use the correct path.

Comment: If it's a public GitLab instance, we *might* be able to reproduce the problem and suggest the correct solution, with an *actual* repository name. If it's a private GitLab instance, we can't. It could be a configuration issue that needs to be addressed by  your organization: a case where local assistance will be far more useful than asking here.

Comment: @tkausl The path is correct since it works using HTTPS. Or, when using SSH I should specify the path in a different way?

Comment: @chepner I installed GitLab in my own server. I have never had problems since I use HTTPS to do all operations. The problem started when I hired a developer that uses MacOS. She cannot clone by either HTTPS or SSH. That is why I tried to clone using SSH in my Windows machine and I couldn't too.

Comment: OK, then this is specifically a GitLab issue (namely you need to configure it to allow SSH connections), not a Git issue.

Comment: @chepner the problem was that I was using my Git user. Git was installed using `git` user so I changed to `git` user and the repository error was gone. I also created the private and public key. Now I can clone using SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem was that I was using my Git user. Git was installed using git user so I changed to git user and the repository error was gone

Any GitLab instance (on-premise or SaaS `gitlab.com`) never allows user SSH access.
It only allows one account, the '`git`' service account.

The user authentication is then performed through the public SSH key used to establish that connection, since said public key is registered to your GitLab account.

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. You need to sort out acces on the repository settings.
2. Create license, terms and certificate file on the repository. By the looks of it it can't authenticate the certificates. It's quite easy git should just create one automatically when you create a repository. Or create one yourself.